# Javascript: разбить массив на n-ое количество частей

Tags: javascript

Как на *JavaScript* можно разбить массив на не более, чем 5 частей в случае разного состава объектов в массиве?

Например, из:

```
a= [{A:'A'},
    {B:'B'},
    {C:'C'},
    {D:'D'},
    {E:'E'},
    {F:'F'},
    {G:'G'},
    {H:'H'},
    {I:'I'}];
```

Получить:

```
b= [{a:{A:'A'}, b:{B:'B'}},
    {c:{C:'C'}, d:{D:'D'}},
    {e:{E:'E'}, f:{F:'F'}},
    {g:{G:'G'}, h:{H:'H'}},
    {i:{I:'I'}}];
```

P.s. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: какие ключи должны быть у частей – алфавит?

Comment: @Sergiks ключи произвольные. Например, от нуля и до числа последнего элемента

Comment: Не всегда можно разделить ровно на 5 частей. Например 11 элементов.

Comment: @Other, Да, но тогда при делении количества элементов на 5 частей, можно округлить в большую сторону. Т.е. должно быть максимум 5 частей, а может быть и вообще одна или две части в зависимости от количества данных

Comment: Тогда стоит указать что нужно **не более** частей, а не конкретное число.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

«Правильный» вариант с [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) – ведь формально мы из массива получаем какое-то одно значение. Тоже массив, в данном случае.

```js
var a = [{A:'A'}, {B:'B'}, {C:'C'}, {D:'D'}, {E:'E'}, {F:'F'}, {G:'G'}, {H:'H'}, {I:'I'}];

function splitTo( arr, n) {
  var plen = Math.ceil(arr.length / n);

  return arr.reduce( function( p, c, i, a) {
    if(i%plen === 0) p.push({});
    p[p.length-1][i] = c;
    return p;
  }, []);
}

var result = splitTo( a, 3);
document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Нужно знать длину отрезка – округлением в бОльшую сторону деления длины на число отрезков.

Метод массива [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) применяет к каждому элементу ф-ю, переданную 1-м параметром, и возвращает одно значение. 2-м параметром даётся начальное значение. Ф-я принимает 4 параметра:

1. «текущее» значение – сначала оно берётся из «начального значения», а потом оно – то, что вернул предыдущий запуск этой ф-ии с предыдущим элементом массива;
2. очередной элемент из массива;
3. индекс очередного элемента;
4. весь массив, на всякий случай.

Внутри поступаем просто. Если индекс делится на длину отрезка без остатка, то пора дописать в результат пустой объект.

И в любом случае в последний элемент результата дописываем ключём – индекс, а значением очередной элемент массива. Прелесть в том, что не нужно проверять какие-то условия, осталось ли что-то в «хвосте» и т.п. Красота!

---

*Первоначальный вариант ответа, принятый ТС:*

Чтобы разделить на 5 (пусть, переменная, `parts`) частей, надо вычислить, какой длины должны быть части:

```
len = Math.ceil( a.length / parts); // округлить в бОльшую сторону
```

И потом идём по элементам, набирая по `len` элементов, пока не закончатся:

```js
var a = [{A:'A'}, {B:'B'}, {C:'C'}, {D:'D'}, {E:'E'}, {F:'F'}, {G:'G'}, {H:'H'}, {I:'I'}];
var parts = 5; // сколько частей

var len = Math.ceil( a.length / parts)
  ,out = []
  ,obj = {}
  ,i
;

for( i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  obj[i] = a[i];
  if( 0 === (i+1)%len) {
    out.push(obj);
    obj = {};
  }
}
if( 0 !== i%len) out.push(obj);

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(out);
```

Считаем элементы исходного массива от 0. В объект-заготовку записываем свойством индекс, а значением – очередной элемент исх. массива:

```
0: {A:'A'}
1: {B:'B'}
..
```

Пора этот сборный объект записать в результат когда следующим, `i+1` индексом, будет кратный длине отрезка, т.е. дающий 0 в остатке от деления. И тогда же, после записи, надо «обнулить» сборный объект для следующей пачки.

Наконец, при выходе из цикла, если в объекте что-то записано, надо этот неполный объект тоже не забыть записать в результат.

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть если массив димаческий и посконно с разным составом данных. Как в таком случае разбить на 5 частей?

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант с использованием метода slice()

```js
function chunkArray(arr, chunk) {
  var i, j, tmp = [];
  for (i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
    tmp.push(arr.slice(i, i + chunk));
  }
  return tmp;
}

var a = [
  {A:'A'},
  {B:'B'},
  {C:'C'},
  {D:'D'},
  {E:'E'},
  {F:'F'},
  {G:'G'},
  {H:'H'},
  {I:'I'}
];

console.log(chunkArray(a, 2));
```

Comment: возвращает массив массивов, а ТС хотел массив объектов с ключами-индексами. И длину чанка надо вычислять, т.к. задача разбить на 5 частей, а даётся массив неопределённой длины.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если строго по твоей задаче то както так(ответ не идеальний конечно).
Если хочешь генерировать ключи то можеш брать значение I или просто себе брать из масива какогото.

```js
var a= [{A:'A'},
{B:'B'},
{C:'C'},
{D:'D'},
{E:'E'},
{F:'F'},
{G:'G'},
{H:'H'},
{I:'I'}];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=2) {
  var objToPush = {};
  var partOne = a[i];
  var keyOne = Object.keys(partOne).shift();
  objToPush[keyOne] = partOne;
  var partTwo = a[i+1];
  if (partTwo) {
    var keyTwo = Object.keys(partTwo).shift();
    objToPush[keyTwo] = partTwo;
  }
  b.push(objToPush)
}
document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(b);
```

Если тебе надо максимум 5 то в for поставь максимум 10 в переборе.

Надеюсь тебе ето поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Подскажите, пожалуйста, если у меня массив динамический и постоянно меняется. То как его разбить на 5 частей?

Answer (score 0):

Последовательное заполнение результирующего массива, строго не судите

```js
let a = [{
    A: 'A'
  },
  {
    B: 'B'
  },
  {
    C: 'C'
  },
  {
    D: 'D'
  },
  {
    E: 'E'
  },
  {
    F: 'F'
  },
  {
    G: 'G'
  },
  {
    H: 'H'
  },
  {
    I: 'I'
  }
];

sliceArray = (arr, n) => {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    newArray[k] = []
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += n) {
    let tempArray = arr.slice(i, i + n);
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (tempArray[j]) {
        newArray[j].push(tempArray[j])
      }
    }

  }
  return newArray

};
console.log(sliceArray(a, 5))
```